# Multi merchants with PayPal API

Tags: asp.net, paypal, sdk

I am a payment processing site for several different companies.  I currently use Cybersource and it allows me to pass transactions under separate company credentials so payments are processed to the correct company.

With PayPal, I am trying to find which API I should use so that I can do an Express Checkout payment and pass different usernames and signatures for different companies.  So far NVP seems like one that would work but I am using VS2015 with ASP.Net (VB).

The SDK for PayPalCoreSDK.Dll uses a Configuration.cs file to store credentials.  I don't know how to provide each company's credentials "on the fly".

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal provides option to use 3rd party API permission. Your system will do the API call and you will include the email address of other companies in subject field to receive the payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/